# Laravel API Project - Design and Authentication

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I am tasked with building an external API for customers. Without giving any business data away, the database consists of our entire workflow. Events generated, associated tickets and other information, all distinguishable by customer.

I want to build an api with very simple endpoints. For each table, say tickets for example, I wish to have two endpoints:

```
/tickets            #will return a list of tickets and general information
/ticket/<ticket_id> #More detailed information about the specific ticket
```

For any customer that authenticates, these routes will only return those DB records for which they are associated.

I have not written a system like this in Laravel before. Am I correct in understanding that Passport is the way to go? I guess I am asking if there are simpler ways to do authentication of this type securely (is Passport overkill)? If we have a small set of customers, and are fine with setting up their authentication for them, would certificates be a better way to go? Or is OAuth2 such the industry standard now that not using Passport is a mistake?

If Passport is best, is it better to have the OAuth2 server and application server be separate sites, or can they be combined into one app?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I like the question, but you ask more then one question with a lot of open area to cover. Might get flagged as to broad. +1 in front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although passport is recommended, you can still use simple API authentication by giving your user an `api_token` attribute. If you set that token in the request headers, Laravel will automaticall authenticate the user. Though you have to use the `auth:api` middleware.

If you use `auth:api` middleware, you can do in your controller `$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();` and it will automatically return the user sending the request.

This post nicely explains what to do: https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51.  It gives the following steps:

1. Add `api_token` to the user migration as string
2. Define a grouped route with middleware in `routes/api.php`

   `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api', 'prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
       Route::resource('tickets', 'TicketController');
   });`

And you are good to go.

The `Route::resource()` with handle both `/tickets` and `/tickets/123` as long as you define `public function index()` and `public function show()` in your controller.

URL to the api call will look like `http://website.com/api/v1` as I prefixed the group with `v1`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this info!

Curious, as you prefaced with the fact that passport is recommended, if you could address Passport with one or two apps? Could passport be roped into the app or is it better to keep them separate?

Comment: I don't understand your question 100% but I think it's related to your last question on your post. Yest, you can combine all in one app. That's what I do for small projects. But for much bigger projects with many team members, we usually split backend (Laravel) from frontend (AngularJS, ReactJS). In all cases, we can still use `passport` or `api_token`.